# Android: Radio button in custom list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, radio-button, android-adapter

I am developing an application in which I need to implement radio buttons in list view. I want to implement a list view having one radio button and two text views in each row. And one button "Ok" below listview.

What I have done is created a list view and a custom adapter.
The code of listview is as:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    tools:ignore="NestedScrolling"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >
</ListView>
```

And I created a custom adapter layout as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radiobutton"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

The java code of fragment is as follows:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

// values is a StringArray holding some string values.
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter (getActivity(), values);
listView.setAdapter(customAdapter );
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {}
```

And the code of the adapter is as follows:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {   
    /** Global declaration of variables. As there scope lies in whole class. */
    private Context context;
    private String[] listOfValues;

    /** Constructor Class */
    public CustomAdapter (Context c,String[] values) {
        super(c,R.layout.adapter_layout,values);
        this.context = c;
        this.listOfValues = values;
    }

    /** Implement getView method for customizing row of list view. */
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        // Creating a view of row.
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, parent, false);
            
            TextView textView1 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            TextView textView2 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);

            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);

            radioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override   
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, CustomAdapter[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    
        return review;
    }
}
```

The data of textview1 are populated from SQLite database and on textview2 the data are "Status Closed". And on the selection of or by clicking any radio button the text of text view gets changed to "Status Open".

**The Issue is:** The need of application is that only one radio button should get selected and data of textview2 get a change on selection. And when the user clicks on the other radio button it gets select and the previous one should get deselect and the text of textview2 gets changed to "Status Closed" of a previously selected radio button and clicked radio button to "Status Open".

**Edit 1:**

And click on the "OK" button I want to get the position, text of list view textview1, and textview2, as I want to save that text in SQLite database in the review.

Please guide me on what steps should I follow. I am in the middle of my application. Your valuable guidance is required.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Here are the key ideas

- when a `RadioButton` is checked we must call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, so that all views get updated.
- when a `RadioButton` is checked we must set a `selectedPosition`, to keep track of which `RadioButton` is selected
- `View`s are recycled inside `ListView`s. Therefore, their absolute position changes in the `ListView`. Therefore, inside `ListAdapter#getView()`, we must call `setTag()` on each `RadioButton`. This allows us to determine the current position of the `RadioButton` in the list when the `RadioButton` is clicked.
- `RadioButton#setChecked()` must be updated inside `getView()` for new or pre-existing `View`s.

Here is an example ArrayAdapter I wrote and tested in order to demonstrate these ideas

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // I do no use these values anywhere inside the ArrayAdapter. I could, but don't.
        final Integer[] values = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,};

        ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.textview, values) {

            int selectedPosition = 0;

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                    RadioButton r = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);
                }
                TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
                tv.setText("Text view #" + position);
                RadioButton r = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);
                r.setChecked(position == selectedPosition);
                r.setTag(position);
                r.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        selectedPosition = (Integer)view.getTag();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                return v;
            }

        };
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I am facing difficulty now too. I am new to this, so I edited my question. Now can you help me out as where to put this code, and how to use this. Your guidence is valuable to me.

Comment: I have added additional code to show how I used the ArrayAdapter. You should be able to get an application working from my code and then modify it to work for your purposes.

Comment: If you have any questions about how to modify SQLite, you should create a second question for that.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am done with your guidance.

Comment: the key ideas you mentioned in this post are really useful

Comment: the radiobuttons are selected initially..but after sum time I m not able to select any radiobutton

Comment: don't use the method notifyDataSetInvalidated(); it will invalidate your listview and show list from top use notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Brian, worked great! Thanks for the information. Was able to use this with the new recyclerview without any issues.

Comment: Instead of setting the tag and getting it back at onClick for position, what would have happened if you had directly used position (the one in getView params)?

Comment: If you anyone wants to get functionality like setSingleChoiceItems() ( persistent single-choice list) then `convertView.setTag(position);
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectedPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });`

Answer (score 2):

Try below adapter :

```
public class ChooseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> {
private ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> listMenu;

int position_id;

private LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;

public ChooseAdapter(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> listMenu, int type) {

    super(activity, R.layout.choose_single_item, listMenu);
    this.listMenu = listMenu;

    context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

public int getCount() {
    return listMenu.size();
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;

}

public static class ViewHolder

{
    public CheckBox chk;

}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder view;

    if (convertView == null) {

        view = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_single_item, null);
        view.chk = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.selection_checkbox);

        view.chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (isChecked) {

                    listMenu.get((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).put(
                            "checked", "true");
                    for (int i = 0; i < listMenu.size(); i++) {
                        if (i != (Integer) buttonView.getTag()) {
                            if (listMenu.get(i).containsKey("checked"))
                                listMenu.get(i).remove("checked");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    listMenu.get((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).remove(
                            "checked");
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(R.id.selection_checkbox, view.chk);
        convertView.setTag(view);

    }

    else {
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    view.chk.setTag(position);

    view.chk.setText(listMenu.get(position).get("name"));

    if (listMenu.get(position).containsKey("checked")) {
        view.chk.setChecked(true);
    } else
        view.chk.setChecked(false);

    return convertView;

}
}
```

And the layout that I am inflating is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/selection_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="abc"
    android:textColor="#8C8C8C"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here, I have used the checkbox, you can also use radiobutton instead of it, nothing else is needed to change.

Hope it helps!