# Why checkedItem in setSingleChoiceItems method of AlertDialog doesn't works?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to set default selected item inside AlertDialog list.

Please see the code below:

```
final CharSequence[] tools = GetTools(toolTypeIndex);
if (tools.length > 0) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final int selectedTool = GetToolIndex();

    if(selectedTool>=0)
    {
        builder.setTitle("Select the tool")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(tools, selectedTool,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            ...
                        }
                    })
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ...
                    }
            })
            .show();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't works. If selectedTool>=0 then always selected only first item by default. If selectedTool==-1 then no selected items.

It is very strange situation. 
I read documentation [AlertDialog.Builder setSingleChoiceItems](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems%28java.lang.CharSequence[],%20int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Maybe, it's an Android bug?

Answer (score 0):

You may also try custom view in Alert Dialog with listview or this may help you

[How can I display a list view in an Android Alert Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762905/how-to-display-list-view-in-alert-dialog-in-android)

Comment: No, I need list of radiobuttons and DEFAULT selected item (first, second, third or any other)

Comment: Then, you should check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347661/android-radio-button-in-custom-list-view/21348318#21348318

Answer (score 0):

This is the bug in Android. What is your API version?