# Check one CheckBox set another uncheck in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

[listView with dual CheckBox Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePYet.jpg)

Am new in Android
I have two checkbox in a list I want to check one at time and unable the other one

my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/student_name"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/present_check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:duplicateParentState="false" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/absent_check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/names_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout
```

Comment: You want to use RadioButtons, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your purpose, just use `RadioButton`, check this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html).

also, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347661/android-radio-button-in-custom-list-view) on how to do that using `RadioButton` and `RadioGroup`

Answer (score 1):

You can use RadioGroup instead Checkbox then add two radioButton to radioGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons are designed exactly for this case. But if you really want to use the checkboxes, when the click event happens for the item in the list on a checkbox, set the other checkbox checked state with the reverse of the current checkbox. So if you receive an event like this pseudo-code:

```
onCheckChanged(CheckBox oneCheckbox, boolean isChecked){
    otherCheckbox.setChecked(!isCchecked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a row in your `listView` is clicked you must call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, so that all views get updated.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
        
// do something
    
notifyDataSetChanged()
});
```